# where to add Vue.config.devtools = true?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

I want to make it so that I can use [Vue.js devtools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en) and am not sure how to do that.

I mean, I guess I need to add `Vue.config.devtools = true` after Vue is loaded but it looks to me like Vue is loaded in some a minified index.html (in the public/my-app directory):

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><base href=/my-app/ ><title>My Application</title><meta charset=utf-8><meta name=description content="My Web Application"><meta name=format-detection content="telephone=no"><meta name=msapplication-tap-highlight content=no><meta name=viewport content="user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,width=device-width"><link rel=icon type=image/ico href=statics/icons/favicon.ico><link href=/my-app/js/0.2a50cd12.js rel=prefetch><link href=/my-app/js/4.70a9b157.js rel=prefetch><link href=/my-app/js/5.9124b006.js rel=prefetch><link href=/my-app/js/6.e59a82a3.js rel=prefetch><link href=/my-app/css/app.b772bed9.css rel=preload as=style><link href=/my-app/js/app.d5445db9.js rel=preload as=script><link href=/my-app/js/runtime.1b6c8c00.js rel=preload as=script><link href=/my-app/js/vendor.ae668b62.js rel=preload as=script><link href=/my-app/css/app.b772bed9.css rel=stylesheet></head><body><div id=q-app></div><script src=/my-app/js/app.d5445db9.js></script><script src=/my-app/js/runtime.1b6c8c00.js></script><script src=/my-app/js/vendor.ae668b62.js></script></body></html>
```

I know that if I make any changes to any of the *.vue files I need to do `quasar build` for those changes to take effect. I suspect that index.html is dynamically generated during the `quasar build` command, which would mean that that is *not* where I should be doing `Vue.config.devtools = true`. So where should I be doing it?

Here's my directory listing:

```
total 1304
-rw-r--r--    1 neubert     staff     147 Feb 21 14:25 .editorconfig
-rw-r--r--    1 neubert     staff     258 Feb 21 14:25 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--    1 neubert     staff     200 Feb 21 14:25 .postcssrc.js
-rw-r--r--    1 neubert     staff     378 Feb 21 14:25 README.md
-rw-r--r--    1 neubert     staff      69 Feb 21 14:25 babel.config.js
drwxr-xr-x    4 neubert     staff     128 Feb 21 14:25 docs
-rw-r--r--    1 neubert     staff  627280 Feb 21 14:25 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r--    1 neubert     staff    1169 Feb 21 14:25 package.json
-rw-r--r--    1 neubert     staff      58 Feb 21 14:25 quasar.extensions.json
drwxr-xr-x    6 neubert     staff     192 Feb 21 14:25 ..
drwxr-xr-x  981 neubert     staff   31392 Feb 21 15:09 node_modules
-rw-r--r--    1 neubert     staff       0 Apr 20 13:51 .env
drwxr-xr-x   12 neubert     staff     384 Apr 24 13:21 src
drwxr-xr-x    6 neubert     staff     192 Apr 24 13:21 .quasar
-rw-r--r--    1 neubert     staff    5660 Apr 24 14:14 quasar.conf.js
drwxr-xr-x   16 neubert     staff     512 Apr 24 14:14 .
```

Comment: If you are using nuxt, use this 
`vue: {
    config: {
      devtools: true,
      productionTip: false,
    },
  }`

Comment: follow this link: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-access-vue-from-chrome-console/3606

Answer (score 1):

So go to **src/main.js** over there you can put this line after all the import statements.
You don't need to put anything in the public directory for this feature to work

Comment: I don't have an **src/main.js**. Here's what I have: https://pastebin.com/kXzb3qdj

Comment: @neubert I'm guessing the file you're looking for is in /src/boot. If your text editor has a global search function (like in VS Code for example) try searching for "createApp" or ".mount("